# DbDeployer - MySQL instance - Grants for new databases (or root user)

Tags: mysql, database, port, dbdeploy

This question relates to [Dbdeployer](https://github.com/datacharmer/dbdeployer/wiki/database-users)

The section in question:

Users:

> root, with the default grants as given by the server version being installed.

I have an instance installed on `port 5730 and port 5731` respectively.  (Corresponds to MySQL 5.7.30 and 5.7.31).

I can connect like this:

```
mysql -u msandbox -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 5730
mysql -u msandbox -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 5731
mysql -u mycustomusername -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 5730
```

I created a file for grants like shown in the article:

> use the option `--post-grants-sql-file` to load the instructions.

```
> cat << EOF > orchestrator.sql

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS orchestrator;
CREATE USER orchestrator IDENTIFIED BY 'msandbox';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON orchestrator.* TO orchestrator;
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.slave_master_info TO orchestrator;

EOF

$ dbdeployer deploy single 5.7 \
  --post-grants-sql-file=$PWD/orchestrator.sql
```

This works fine for a **new empty database deployed by the SQL script (and its grants), but I now have an *existing* instance, and want to create a new database from *within the mysql instance***.

The article claims that `root` should be available, but:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 5731
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

*I have the local instance installed on 3306, but this is not supposed to be the user I need to login with*.

When I do this:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 5731
```

I am able to login, _however this seems to ignore the port (when connecting as `localhost`) because I see *different databases (those on port 3306 and not those from 5730/5731)*!

This also confirms my suspicion that port gets ignored :

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR mycustomusername;
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'mycustomusername' on host '%'

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%port%';
.... truncated ....
port   | 3306
```

I need to use `root@host5731` and `root@host5730`  but there does not seem a way to use root here?

I need to do one (either) of the following:

- Use `root` user at these ports,
- Get a way to let `msandbox` or `mycustomusername` to be able to have ability to do `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` **on a new database.**

#### Why?

I cannot remove/recreate a new MySQL instance to add new databases (using the SQL file method) `--post-grants-sql-file` when I already have existing databases.

Answer (score 1):

Dbdeployer instances and setup installed and configures the password for `root` to be the same password as the username specified (default username `msandbox`).

**You cannot do this (even though some answers on the github repo claim you can)**

```
dbdeployer deploy single 5.7.31 -u root -p somepassword
```

Rather what happens (and not clearly mentioned anywhere easily accessible) is that you can do the following:

```
dbdeployer deploy single 5.7.31 -u someuser -p somepassword
```

Dbdeployer setup then deploys this `someuser` **AND** `root` to have the same password (`somepassword`).

### More information:

I found that I could do this:

```
cd /var/dbdeployer/instance/location/of/mysql.5.7.31/
./use -u root
```

*(Not specifying the password here.)*
Inspecting the `./use` script, it greps the password from your configuration (which is the password for `someuser`.

This then gives us the ability to login via `root` to change grants:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 5731
```

I have now changed the password from inside:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password';
```

This prevents you from externally using `./use -u root` as the password is now different than the other user.